# prolog lists fd_all_different and is_set whats faster?

Tags: list, prolog, set, clpfd

i just want to know if anyone of you knows whats faster,

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5], all_different(L). % needs use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

or

```
L=[1,2,3,4,5], is_set(L).
```

anyone knows? need the faster solution for my sudoku solver. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the predicate time/1 to measure the number of inferences and actual time taken to do the computation.
In your example you would do something like

```
time((L=[1,2,3,4,5], all_different(L))) vs. time((L=[1,2,3,4,5], is_set(L)))
```

Note that the time measured is up to the first success.

Comment: > 4 ?- time((L=[1,2,3,4,5], all_different(L))).
> % 165 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

> 5 ?- time((L=[1,2,3,4,5], is_set(L))).
> % 11 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (?% CPU, Infinite Lips)
> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

so that mean is_set is faster? 11 < 165?

Comment: @viktor: Well, your sample input was a bit short to really tell (0.000 CPU for both), but it seems that the latter was better.

Answer (score 2):

A distinction between **all_different/1** and **is_set/1** is that the former uses "constraint logic" and can impose a prospective restriction before the entries of a list are fully instantiated, such that failure occurs when the Prolog engine is compelled to unify or assign equal values to two of the list argument's entries.

We can illustrate the "constraint logic" of **all_different** with the following pair of queries:

```
?- length(L,5), all_different(L), L=[1,2,3,4,5].
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

?- length(L,5), all_different(L), L=[1,2,3,4,1].
false.
```

It is necessary to provide a proper list to **all_different** but not to have one of fully bound or "ground" entries.  The above shows that **all_different** can prospectively impose a constraint on a list's entries.

Compare the results with **is_set** instead:

```
?- length(L,5), is_set(L), L=[1,2,3,4,5].
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].

?- length(L,5), is_set(L), L=[1,2,3,4,1].
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 1].
```

Once **is_set** succeeds, it cannot prevent future bindings that created equal entries.

So the predicate **all_different** relies on extra machinery in the constraint logic library to do what **is_set** cannot, and in most cases this extra machinery will add to the overhead.  However in the simple way it was used in viktor's question, the extra machinery is not used very much.  Checks are done on fully bound terms, not in a prospective manner, and the efficiency is comparable.